# ML w/ Nested Data (Event data to help with Churn)

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing, churn

My personal experience with ML is strictly tied to Coursera ML class. Most of their classes are really good, but I never figured out how to apply it to my data.

My question is; I have a lot of user event data that basically says, this user clicked on A,B,C and views page X,Y,Z. My data is nested with users and all their events under that user. Overall I want to use this data to help with churn.

When I look at AWS ML tech, all examples I normally find are basically a flat excel sheet with one line per user.

How do you use nested data with ML? I can flatted the data, but i.e. how do you tell the ML algorithm that the next 10 lines are for the same user?

Comment: Welcome to cross validated. When you say data nested, you just mean many observations about the same user, correct?

Comment: That is correct